# Tor Won't Launch

Tags: configuration, windows, help, onion-routing, error

Every time since last night when I try to launch TOR I get "Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start." Restarting TOR does nothing. It just keeps happening no matter what I do. How is this fixed?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. It worked fine before last night.

Comment: Still happening. It goes to a big page that says the same thing but no way to make TOR work. Never connects. Sometimes it gives another error message after closing the TOR connection which I don't remember as I can't get that far anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have edited the torrc file to open a port check this answer [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16015/19668)

if not, you might have 2 copies of tor running in the same time (Tor + a tor service). To disable that open a command windows navigate to `....\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor` and  launch this command `tor --service remove` (it outputs nothing). Then try again to launch tor. (all credit to the link above)